# Merging similar entries in SQL database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a database where I record the guests of a TV show and which episodes they have appeared in. Mainly I have three tables:

Guest (name, ID)

Episode (Date, topics, ID)

EpisodeGuest (Episode ID, GuestID)

However, upon inspection I find that many guests are recorded several times with a slight different spelling of their name. This is somewhat out of my control as I webscrape the appearances of a guest from a website.

Example:

`Peter N. Larsson`

`Peter N Larsson`

`Peter N. Larson`

These names now are recorded as multiple guests with multiple appearances. How can I merge these as the same person, without doing it manually? The guests are entered with Surname and Lastname, so in all cases where, lets say, only 3 characters differ between two names its safe (enough) to say that its the same guest.

Is the best way to merge this to go through every name, search for something remotely similar within 3 characters, and merge by editing the EpisodeGuest table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a module called [fuzzystrmatch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/fuzzystrmatch.html). This module contains functions that can help. My inclination is to suggest Levenshtein distance, but you may find that the other functions in the module work for you.

I will caution you about this approach. First, the fact that two names look very similar does not mean that they are the same person. Second, you will need to manually check the results.

However, the idea would be to get the candidates using something like this:

```
select t.name, t2.name
from t join
     t2
     on levenshtein(t.name, t2.name) < 4 and -- arbitrary number
        t.name <> t2.name;
```